# Prestashop 1.7.7.4 slow admin list orders

Tags: controller, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

We have a Prestashop 1.7.7.4 and the "Orders" administration page (/sell/orders/) takes 35619.8ms to load.

We set `addonsRequest` to `false`, but the problem remains.

With debug mode we can see that Controller takes too much time:

[image]

What can it be due to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by notification counters in the top horizontal bar being loaded with heavy and slow queries.

Have look at [this](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/23827) issue where you can find some suggested workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I finally found the bottleneck: the Packlink PRO shipping module has 147 queries: [image]

And not exactly fast:
[image]

Comment: It seems that your module has (n + 1) problem and needs to be fixed